# Django-admin: images in zip file and inserting each image info in a database

Tags: python, django

I want to build an image gallery using Django. Each image is a post, of course. Now, I don't want to be uploading each image independently. I want to zip them all and upload them in the Django admin page and *maybe* create some kind of a trigger to:

- decompressed the zip
- read all the images info
- store the info in a database, each image in a row

Is this possible with Django? what would be your best way to accomplish this? I'll appreciate any kind of help, I'm very new to Django (like 5 hours new)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Here is a broad outline inspired entirely by how [Mezzanine](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/galleries/models.py) implements this.

First you define a field for accepting the zip file:

```
class BaseGallery(models.Model):
    zip_import = models.FileField(blank=True, upload_to=upload_to("galleries")
```

Then you have a separate model that is Foreign keyed to your parent model. In the example here the parent model is `BaseGallery` and the image model is `GalleryImage`:

```
class GalleryImage(Orderable):
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name="images")
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to="galleries")
```

Then in your model's `save` method, you can extract this zip file and save the individual images:

```
from django.core.files import ContentFile
from django.conf import settings
from zipfile import ZipFile

def save(self, delete_zip_import=True, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    If a zip file is uploaded, extract any images from it and add
    them to the gallery, before removing the zip file.
    """
    super(BaseGallery, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.zip_import:
        zip_file = ZipFile(self.zip_import)
        for name in zip_file.namelist():
            data = zip_file.read(name)
            try:
                from PIL import Image
                image = Image.open(BytesIO(data))
                image.load()
                image = Image.open(BytesIO(data))
                image.verify()
            except ImportError:
                pass
            except:
                continue
            name = os.path.split(name)[1]
            # You now have an image which you can save
            path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "galleries", 
                                    native(str(name, errors="ignore")))
            saved_path = default_storage.save(path, ContentFile(data))
            self.images.create(file=saved_path)
        if delete_zip_import:
            zip_file.close()
            self.zip_import.delete(save=True)
```

Note, the bit where the image is actually saved has been simplified and if you look at the source I have linked to there is a bit more jiggery-pokery required to handle unicode file names etc.

Also note that Mezzanine uses its own `FileField` which isn't the same as Django's `FileField`. I have tried to refactor this in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code to extract files from an uploaded ZIP file:

## source

```
import zipfile

localFile = 'beer.zip'

with zipfile.ZipFile(localFile, 'r') as myzip:
    myzip.extractall()
    print 'got:', [info.filename for info in myzip.infolist()]
```

## reference

- [Python zipfile module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html)